# Jackson dealing with different image JSON formats

Tags: json, jackson, json-ld, jackson-databind

I'm trying to process JSON that sometimes has different formats for the image tag:

```
"image": [
    "https:\/\/tmbidigitalassetsazure.blob.core.windows.net\/secure\/RMS\/attachments\/37\/1200x1200\/Cheesy-Cauliflower-Breadsticks_EXPS_THCOMS17_207460_B09_08_3b.jpg",
    [
        "https:\/\/cdn3.tmbi.com\/toh\/GoogleImages\/Cheesy-Cauliflower-Breadsticks_EXPS_THCOMS17_207460_B09_08_3b.jpg"
    ],
    [
        "https:\/\/cdn3.tmbi.com\/toh\/GoogleImagesPostCard\/Cheesy-Cauliflower-Breadsticks_EXPS_THCOMS17_207460_B09_08_3b.jpg"
    ]
],
```

or

```
"image": "http://someimage"
```

or

```
"image": [
"https://alldayidreamaboutfood.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Garlic-Parmesan-Wings.jpg"
]
```

and finally

```
"image": {
  "@type": "ImageObject",
  "url": "http://cdn.ampproject.org/leader.jpg",
  "height": 200,
  "width": 200
},
```

My code has:

```
  @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
  private String[] image;
```

THis seems to work for the 2nd and 3rd example but is throwing an exception for the first:

```
Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token
```

Any tips on how to deal with this type of variation?